# Объединить метки [лямбда-выражение] и [lambda]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [лямбда-выражение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [lambda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda) в сторону русскоязычной. Для [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) в таком объединении я уверен. Для [других имеющихся вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda%20-c%2B%2B) хорошо бы услышать мнения других участников по языкам [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) и [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Время идёт (модераторы бездействуют), появилась ещё и [лямбда-выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) (множественное число).

Comment: почему не просто [tag:lambda] или [tag:лямбда]?

Comment: @Grundy в с++ это именно lambda expression

Comment: @Grundy, ну тут же не сайт по греческому языку, а по программированию. Термин [tag:лямбда-выражение] более узок и яснее выражает тематику сайта.

Comment: А почему не лямбда-исчисление, например?

Comment: @D-side в с++ это именно lambda expression

Comment: @alexolut я про объединение с lambda.

Comment: @D-side исчисление, имхо, более к математике относится. Хотя на enSO есть и [lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda) и [lambda-calculus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus). Первых на порядок больше.

Comment: @alexolut я к тому, что синонимизация этих меток может быть неуместна, скорее замена на [tag:лямбда-выражение], где это применимо. На enSO избежать коллапса метки в хаос не успели. Может, мы сможем.

Comment: @D-side в чём коллапс-то?

Comment: @alexolut в том, что неоднозначная метка закрепилась.

Comment: @D-side много желающих видеть раздельно вопросы [lambda-expression] и [lambda]?

Comment: Хотел написать что "лябмда-выражения" - это метка из того же ряда, что и "массивы", "функции", "цикл". и ее надо сжечь следом за ними - но тут обнаружил, что у метка "массивы" мало того что существует, так у нее 24 подписчика...

Comment: Я согласен, лучше

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Это писалось как комментарий к [ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5169/176217) @D-side, но в границы комментария не уложилось.</sub>

В принципе, любая метка неоднозначна, если для неё нет соответствующего описания. Но имеет смысл учитывать текущие реалии, если в большинстве случаев под термином "лямбда" будет пониматься "лямбда-выражение", то [лямбда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0) вполне сойдёт за основную метку. В частности из-за своей краткости.

AWS Lambda совершенно спокойно может стать отдельной меткой вида [aws-lambda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-lambda).

Пример с греческой буквой я считаю вовсе надуманным. Никто в здравом уме не будет создавать метку для буквы алфавита. Интересно, кому бы была интересна подписка на такие вопросы?

Выделять отдельно [лямбда-исчисление](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) тоже кажется сомнительным. Так как это в первую очередь математический термин. А реализация лямбда-исчислений на языках программирования (ведь Stack Overflow это сайт о программировании) как раз будет относиться к лямбда-выражению.

Comment: лямбда могла бы к какому-нибудь хаскелю относиться, может быть даже как оператор какой-нибудь

Comment: @Grundy не совсем понял. Не могли бы уточнить?

Comment: ну символ лямбды

Comment: @Grundy имеем символ `λ` ... что дальше?

Comment: Как по мне лямбда исчисление находится достаточно далеко от лямбда выражения в его понимании в стандартных языках программирования

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev а считаете ли Вы вообще уместным наличие метки [tag:лямбда-исчисление] на ruSO?

Comment: @alexolut Да, я думаю, вопросы по этой теме хуже точно не сделают

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev а их еще нет на сайте? Под имеющимися метками.

Comment: @alexolut Пока видел только один вопрос, но с него слетела метка, так как он был один долгое время

Answer (score 2):

Метки [lambda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda) и [лямбда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0), неоднозначны. Они могут быть:

- Про лямбда-выражения и лямбда-функции
- Про лямбда-исчисление
- Про [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/lambda/)
- Про одноимённую греческую букву

  - (мало ли в каком контексте: ТеХ, употребление символа в коде, юникод)
- ... (что-то ещё? название довольно ходовое в области функциональщины)

Посему...

#### синонимизацию [lambda-expression](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda-expression) и аналогов к [lambda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda) считаю недопустимой

Предлагаю такую:

- **[лямбда-выражение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)** : [лямбда-функция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f), [lambda-expression](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda-expression)

  - И добавить описание, разумеется.

А вопросам из [lambda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda) после этого предлагаю переставить метки на правильные. Сейчас там 50 вопросов. Бывало и хуже.

Тегу [lambda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda), свою очередь, предлагаю добавить описание с рекомендацией не использовать эту метку. Поскольку метки ранжируются преимущественно по числу вопросов, после вышеупомянутых мер она должна постепенно выйти из употребления.

Comment: описание с рекомендацией не использовать метку не работает. все равно будут ставить

Comment: @PashaPash надо написать так, чтоб не ставили. ЕСЛИ ВЫ ПОСТАВИТЕ ЭТУ МЕТКУ, У ВАС БОЛЬШЕ НИКОГДА ... придумать окончание :)

Comment: @alexolut У ВАС ПЕРЕСТАНЕТ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно пойти по стопам enSO и сделать основной [лямбда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0) (всё-таки предпочитаю русскоязычную версию у нас), как предположил в [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5167/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-lambda/5168#comment19105_5167) @Grundy. [lambda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda), [лямбда-выражение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [лямбда-функция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) сделать синонимами.